# Pandas to_sql() not working with PostgreSQL - value too long for type character varying

Tags: python, django, postgresql, pandas, django-models

I'm using Pandas with SQLAlchemy to apply some ETL on one CSV file

After validating the fields and transforming some of them I try to export to my PostgreSQL database, but I'm getting one error which does not make sense:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.DataError: (psycopg2.DataError) value too long for type character varying(50)
```

I already changed the field to many values (it was initially setup as 15). I tried to get `NaN` values for that field and replacing with '' (there was only one field). For that I used:

```
>>> df.loc[df['foo'].isnull(), 'foo'] = ''
```

I tried changing the `chunksize` to 5000 and 1000. Initially, it was not set.

```
>>> df.to_sql("mytable", con, index=False, if_exists='append', chunksize=1000)
```

The command above worked with `sqlite`

After having those problems I checked the column which was throwing the error again to see if there was any problem with its length. Apparently, it did not, but I ran the following code anyway:

```
>>> df.foo.str.len().max() 
11.0
```

I also tried the following:

```
>>> df.fillna(value='', inplace=True)
>>> df['foo'] = df['foo'].str.strip()
```

Then I also added

```
for f in Inventory._meta.get_fields():
    if f.get_internal_type() == 'CharField':
        df[f.name] = df[f.name].str[:f.max_length]
```

But it did not work either

I finally put the length of the column to 100, but this is not right. The field contains only 11 char per row. I ran out of ideas. This error is strange, and I'd appreciate some help.

Comment: Have you tried `df.foo = df.foo.str.strip()`? There might be a bunch of whitespace that is causing your issue.

Comment: I tried a few minutes ago and it did not work. I also tried `fillna()`

Comment: Is the column a string? You might want to try to change the column type in Postgres to text to see if that helps. Also are you sure that it's the foo column giving the issue?

Comment: Yes, it is a string. I know it is the column, because I changed the value of its length to different values and it was always throwing errors with those specific values. When I changed to 100 it worked... :(. I know I can change to text and there is not really a performance issue, but I'm wondering what is the problem here. It might happen in the future again and this is strange. We usually assign a size for consistency and to save storage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it's pretty embarrassing what happened. The code above was right since the beginning. The problem is that I'm merging some rows and concatenating in that column the merged values in a different function and I forgot. I thought the error was only in my validation function when it was never there.

What did I do to find it out?

I change the value of the column to a big value (100) so the code above would work, then I ran the following SQL:

```
SELECT length(foo) AS ln_foo FROM inventory WHERE length(foo) > 11
```